# How to count the object number instead of getting all object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For Example, I want to know the User have how many post. So, I do it in this way;

```
user.posts.length
```

It works, but when I see the server log, it shows me that:

```
SELECT * FROM "posts" WHERE ("posts".user_id = 6)
```

actually, I need to know the post number only, how can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
user.posts.count

# This will generate this:
SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM `posts` WHERE (`posts`.user_id = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 user.posts.count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use count/size method instead of length:

```
user.posts.count
```

It will execute query similar to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_id FROM "posts" WHERE ("posts".user_id = 6)
```